# Are flat local morphisms of local rings always faithfully flat injections?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I claim that flat local maps $(A, m_A) \to (B, m_B)$ are faithfully flat injections. To show faithful flatness of $B$ it suffices to show that $B \otimes_A k(m_A) = B/m_AB \neq 0$.  However, by the local morphism definition, we know that $m_AB \subset m_B$ so that there is an induced surjection $B/m_AB \to k(m_B)$. In particular, $B/m_AB \neq 0$ so the map is faithfully flat.

Now, we want to show the map is injective. Indeed, if $K$ is the kernel, then $K \otimes_A B = 0$ which implies $K = 0$ by faithful flatness, since $B$ is a nonzero $A$-module. (see Stacks [Lemma 10.39.15](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HP)).

Is this reasoning correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you need more justification why $K\otimes_A B=0$. You have an injection $K\hookrightarrow A$ which you're tensoring with $B$ to get an injection $K\otimes_A B\hookrightarrow B$ where injectivity comes from flatness. The image is $KB$ so you're getting $K\otimes_A B\simeq KB=0$. Now the rest of what you say works.

Inspecting your proof you see that *any* faithfully flat morphism is injective, so together with your first paragraph (which all looks good) you have separately (flat + local implies faithfully flat) and (faithfully flat implies injective).